# How do I select the first value of of a parameter to be the default value?

Tags: reportbuilder3.0, reportbuilder

I want to show a default value in the dropdown for my parameters. The thing is, my parameter doesn't reference a Dataset but it references another parameter. So I want the default value of parameter 2 to be the selected value of parameter 1.

I can't seem to get it to work. I my specific case I want "DisplayMonat" to default to the selected value from "Monat" and not .

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: If the value for DisplayMonat will be Monat, why do you need DisplayMonat anyway?, can you not just use the value from Monat to filter your data for both values

Comment: @A.Steer Because I use Format() for DisplayMonat.

Comment: but why can you not just do that on Monat?

Comment: Because I don't want Monat to be formatted

Answer (score 0):

If you want the value of Monat to be in DisplayMonat, the default value of DisplayMonat would be `Parameters!Monat.Value`.

If you want the value in DisplayMonat to be what you see in the drop down menu for Monat, then you can use `Parameters!Monat.Label`.

Both of these can be set in the **Report Parameter Properties** dialog box, under the section for **Default Values**

[image]